# How can I generate PHP documentation using phpdoc or similar application under Netbeans 7.0?

Tags: php, unix, netbeans, ubuntu, phpdoc

I've just wondering is there any possibility to generate a PHP documentation with phpdoc or any similar application under Netbeans 7.0 at Ubuntu for PHP project, which has classes used like in java, something like

```
class tech.lib.facade.Html extends tech.lib.facade.Builder { ...
```

when I'm using phpdoc with normal way it doesn't create any connections and doesn't generate any methods from classes.

Is there any way to configure this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question...  are you saying you want phpdoc to document PHP code where you have class names that contain dots?  That's not a valid class naming format (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123660/dot-in-a-php-class-name), so it's not likely that phpdoc can even parse such code.

Comment: not really, i mean classes and packages also, like `main.libs.text.Editor` where main.libs.text is package.

Comment: I'm not aware of dots being disallowed in package names, but again, PHP itself won't allow dots in the class names.  So, you could certainly have your code show just "class Editor {}" while your docblock shows "package main.libs.text".